# Gridview edit column position

Tags: gridview, indexing, edit

I would like to know how to change the edit column position after setting `AutoGenerateEditButton="true"`. By default it is displayed always on the left as the 1st column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use   `<asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />` to define your edit column